# SQL Server 2016 Express Setup with ConfigurationFile.ini

Tags: sql-server

I'm making ConfigurationFile.ini for auto installation.

But as you know, SQL Server 2016 installation has splitted SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio)

So, ConfigurationFile.ini cannot include SSMS installation

How can I included SSMS to whole auto installation procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, this cannot be done. But with SSMS itself, you can use /quite switch to perform a quite install. For example:
    SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe /install /quite

Comment: I think you mean `quiet`?

Comment: Oops, my bad.  Yes i mean quiet.